# Stock ledger query from one table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table

```
DocumentNumber, ItemNumber, Qty,
-----------------------------------
600000001,  1006YL01,   1
100001976,  1006YL01,   -1
100008439,  1006YL08,   -1
600000001,  1006YL08,   1
100005095,  1006YL08,   -1
100003814,  1006YL08,   -1
100002955,  1006YL08,   -1
500000087,  1006YL08,   2
500000212,  1006YL08,   1
100001152,  1006YL09,   -1
100004799,  1006YL09,   -1
500000282,  1006YL09,   2
100002859,  1006YL09,   -1
600000001,  1006YL09,   2
100003625,  1006YL09,   -1
600000001,  1006YL10,   2
100003274,  1006YL10,   -1
100002451,  1006YL10,   -1
```

I want to make a query which returns

```
Document Number, ItemNumber, ReceiveQty (from qty >1), Issue Qty (from qty<1)
```

Can any body help?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  DocumentNumber, 
        ItemNumber,
        SUM(CASE WHEN qty > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_LessThanOne,
        SUM(CASE WHEN qty < 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Total_GreaterThanOne
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY DocumentNumber, ItemNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  DocumentNumber
        ,ItemNumber
        ,CASE WHEN Qty > 1 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END ReceiveQty 
        ,CASE WHEN Qty < 1 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END IssueQty
FROM    Table1
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e06b/1)

You can also use this one in MySQL:

```
SELECT  DocumentNumber
        ,ItemNumber
        ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Qty > 1 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) ReceiveQty 
        ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Qty < 1 THEN Qty ELSE 0 END) IssueQty
FROM    Table1
GROUP   BY DocumentNumber, ItemNumber
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7167/5)

Comment: is group_concat mysql? The question relates to t-sql